# Добавление одной строки в конец другой

Tags: c, строки

Функция должна добавить в конец `string1` строку `string2` (в `string1` всегда хватает места для `string2`):

```
char *strcat(char *string1, const char *string2) {
    char * str = string1; // теперь str - указатель на первую ячейку массива
    while (*(++str)); // двигаю str до конца дин. массива типа char
    while ((*(str++) = *(string2++))); // изменяю значения после '\0'
    return string1;
}
```

Тестил, вроде все работает правильно, но на тесте валится. Помогите найти ошибку.

Comment: а 0-символ в конец почему не записали?

Comment: while((*(str++) = *(string2++))); остановится на моменте, когда в str будет 0.

Comment: Как именно валится и на каком тесте?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не знаю, на каком именно вводе валится. А так, неправильный ответ.

Comment: @AnT неправильный ответ.

Comment: @AnT "Вам требуется реализовать свою версию функции strcat из библиотеки cstring для работы с C-строками. Эта функция должна иметь такой заголовок:
char * strcat(char * str1, const char * str2);".

Comment: Если бы отправляли null-pointer, функция бы выдавала неопределенное поведение, т.е. скорее всего ошибка была бы RE. Нет, именно str1.

Comment: @AnT случайно нажал. Нет, в точности этот. Спасибо. Попробую найти ошибку.

Comment: Действительно, я вас вводил в заблуждение. Явная ошибка наличествует в первом цикле, как написано в ответе от @Vlad from Moscow.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c#L245

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уже в этом цикле

```
while (*(++str));
```

имеется проблема. Например, если строка `str` пустая, то ее первый символ - это символ завершающего нуля `'\0'`. Однако так как указатель сначала инкрементируется `++str`, то этот ноль просто проскакивается, и функция имеет неопределенное поведение.

Поэтому правильно будет определить функцию следующим образом

```
char *strcat(char *string1, const char *string2) 
{
    char *str = string1; // теперь str - указатель на первую ячейку массива

    while ( *str ) ++str; // двигаю str до конца дин. массива типа char
    while ( ( *str++ = *string2++ ) ); // изменяю значения после '\0'

    return string1;
}
```

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо.